# store object during a 10 minute window

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a problem that was posed at an interview exercise. I wasn't able to solve it during the interview so I am asking for your help to do it know.

The problem is:

Write a class with a method that takes an integer and returns the integer that is the greatest value that the method has been called with in the last ten minutes.

From what I understand I have to store all the values which the method was called for the last 10 minutes. The values should be stored in an efficient data structure because this method might be invoked several times per second.

Do you have any suggestion for what data structure should be more efficient for this?
Also, as this is a time rolling window, how can I clean the values that are expired?

And what should be the best way to get the max value, depending of the data structure used?

I have some base code:

```
    private final static ScheduledExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); 

    private static List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    public int method(final int value){
        values.add(value);

         // Task to remove the key-value pair     
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {     
            @Override     
            public void run() {     
                values.remove(value);
            }     
        };     

        // Schedule the task to run after the delay  
        EXECUTOR_SERVICE.schedule(task, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  


        //TODO get the max value
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: the scheduler is overkill; it is better to do cleanup only as new entries arrive (or the 'max' is actually requested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can actually be done in amortized constant time:

```pseudo
values := deque of timestamped values

function prune()
    while values.front is older than 10 minutes
        values.pop_front()

function add(v)
    while values is not empty and v is greater than values.back
        values.pop_back()
    values.push_back(v)

function getMax()
    prune()
    return values.front()
```

The values are stored in decreasing order using the observation that when you get a new value you may forget about smaller, older values.

Comment: Surprisingly elegant - congrats.

Comment: This solution is really simple and efficient. I already implemented it and it runs quite fast! thanks

Answer (score 5):

Define an `Entry` class as made up of a (timestamp) `time` and an (int) `value`;

Use a `LinkedList<Entry>` to keep the sliding window: insert at end, remove expired at beginning. Use a `TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Entry>>` to keep an O(1) lookup for the max value (use `.lastEntry()` to get at the max value). The idea would be to sort by `value` and keep the list of all entries with that value; the tree would have to be updated (in O(log(N)) once for each entry added or removed.

Do not use the scheduler; do cleanup whenever a new request arrives (or the 'max' is requested), it is cheaper and faster.

Comment: If you store the max value, then on insert/delete you can instantly tell whether or not you need to compute a new max - and insert becomes an O(1) operation.

Comment: "use a descending comparator instead of the default ascending one" => no need, there is a `firstEntry` AND a `lastEntry` method.

Comment: @SubSevn If you only store the max, recomputing it is O(n). If you use a TreeMap and update it after each operation, it's O(log n).

Comment: @tom I guess I should clarify, you only need to recompute on delete, and when you do delete, you can take advantage of the TreeMap and make it an O(log n) operation.  The point of storing the max is to reduce recomputations, which doesn't reduce the worst case complexity for deletion, but would save clock cycles in real implementation.

Comment: @SubSevn but you need to insert everything into the treemap or the deletes will not be consistent (insert 10 equally-max values, remove 9: one is still left; vs remove the 10: have to search for previous). No real savings from storing max separately - either the tree is up to date, or it is not useful.

Comment: @tucuxi What I meant was, if you keep the max, you can do an insert without recomputing, since you'll know that you don't need to recompute.  Unless your insert can, at insert speed, perform the recomputation - at which point storing the max is pointless.

Comment: @tucuxi Which it looks like a TreeMap would do, so yes, no reason to keep the max.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments about your code:

- `values.remove(value);` is calling `remove(int index)` not `remove(Object o)`. So it will remove the value located at an index=value. You can use `values.remove(Integer.valueOf(value));` instead for example
- You have not provided the part that returns the max value - but with a list you will need to browse the whole list to find the max, so that method will be O(n), which is not very efficient.
- the idea of using a scheduler to remove the value 1 minute later is fine

Alternative 1:

- create a holder class:

  ```
  class Holder {
      private static AtomicInteger staticVersionCounter = new AtomicInteger();
      private int value;
      private int version;
  }
  ```
- when you receive a new `int`, create a `new Holder(value, staticVersionCounter.incrementAndGet());` and place it in a `TreeSet` with a custom comparator that sorts by ascending value and version (to make sure identical values are not overwritten)
- the max can be efficiently retrieved with the `TreeSet#last()` method
- you can keep the scheduler to remove the entry after the expiration period

Comment: You should describe how you remove objects from the `TreeSet`. Presumably something along the lines of `set.remove(set.ceil(new Holder(valueToRemove, 0)))`.

Comment: @tom Same way as in the Op's code: create a `final Holder h = ...` then in the task: `treeset.remove(h);`.

Comment: @tom Your proposal is interesting but would not work with the comparator I propose in my answer (values are sorted by value, not by insertion order).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `LinkedList<IntegerTimePair>` and in doing so, you can easily get the first element, but also easily get (and remove) elements at the end (the oldest ones) - a LinkedList is good for that since there's no shifting like in an ArrayList.  My first guess would be to check at some interval, starting from the back of the list, removing all of the ones that are more than ten minutes old.

My only question would be whether or not Java's LinkedList is bidirectional and maintains the beginning and end.  If not, write one that's got operations like removeFromEnd(), using the stored tail pointer.

Getting the max value can be done using a scan of the list, or by maintaining the max value and only updating it when you insert a new value higher, OR when you delete, scanning for the newest max value (if you deleted the max value).

Comment: You would need to create IntegerTimePair yourself, but it would just store the Integer and the time.